# Узнать размер и тип файла до загрузки на сервер

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть [файлообменник](http://www.putit.ru) при загрузке большого файла, он только после загрузки на сервер говорит, что, мол, файл превышает допустимую норму (25 мб), либо то, что файлы такого вида запрещены к загрузке вообще (php, к примеру). Так вот, чтобы зря не гонять трафик людей и не ждать загрузки, чтобы обломаться, хочу информировать пользователей сразу, мол, файл превышает норму, или тип не верный, это можно сделать? Средствами javascript или jquery? Что почитать?

Comment: повтор [вопроса](http://habrahabr.ru/qa/20709/)

Comment: @Spectre, это хорошо, что Вы такой глазастый. 

IMHO @butteff просто не удовлетворен ответом с хабра (imho ответ про размер там вообще не на этот вопрос. Спрашивают про Upload, а отвечают про Download).

--

@butteff, с типом наверное тоже не все так просто. IMHO сервер должен анализировать содержимое, а не расширение файла (иначе это туфта).

Comment: @avp, почему-же? По моему, вторая ссылка с примером использования [File.size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/File) из [FileAPI](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) вполне отвечает на данный вопрос. Другое дело, что это [не везде будет работать](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi), но других вариантов без сторонних плагинов, вроде бы, нету.

PS Mime type можно проверить там-же.

Comment: @Ilya Pirogov, в своем комментарии Вы дали 3 ссылки. 

Если откровенно, черз 15 минут их изучения, я так и не понял, как можно узнать у сервера, примет ли он файл данного размера. 

Мне показалось, что объект FileList относится к локальным (для браузера) файлам. А про Upload, что можно узнать "прогресс" загрузки.

*Я не прав ?*

--

Возможно @butteff более мотивирован и выкопает там ответ на свой вопрос.

Comment: @Ilya Pirogov, я понял именно "Как динамически определить...". 

Если же "проверить в **браузере**", то все правильно и мои комментарии неуместны. По крайней мере про размер. Про тип - посмотреть расширение файла - это слишком очевидно.

Но, лучше пусть ТС уточнит, что он имел в виду.

Comment: По контенту определить тип тоже можно при помощи [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Blob), но это уже совсем не тривиальная задача... хотя и интересная.

Comment: @Ilya Pirogov, не знаю как для всех файлов, в общем и целом, а для изображений, узнать расширение по первым битам - элементарно.

Comment: @Ilya Pirogov, "...но это уже совсем не тривиальная задача..."

--

Переносим (с Си на JS) unix утилиту file, *а потом и весь \*nix, превращая браузер в очередную виртуалку* (шутка конечно). 

Радуемся, как просто стало программировать и огорчаемся, что медленно.

На самом деле тут проблема (из-за безопасности) в невозможности доступа к native OS.

Comment: @AlexWindHope, наверное, ~95% всех типов можно определить по первым байтам :) Однако это вовсе не делает задачу элементарной, поскольку для каждого типа нужно хранить от одной и более сигнатур. При этом структура сигнатур может очень сильно отличаться.

PS Только картинок существует порядка 50 типов, а ведь бывают еще и разные версии одного и того же формата. Кроме того, в данном случае про картинки речи не было.

@avp, т.е. считаете портирование утилиты file на javascript тривиальной задачей? :) Что ж, @butteff, ответ на ваш вопрос предельно прост - портируйте file на js и дело в шляпе!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Как узнать размер](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1440804).

[Как узнать расширение](https://stackoverflow.com/a/651735).

Comment: @caravaneer, По возможности, пожалуйста, пишите развернутые ответы.

Comment: **На** сервер, а не **с** сервера.

Comment: @caravaner, не пойму почему сервер будет правильно воспринимать http **HEAD** для URL, который **собираются передать на сервер** т.е. методом **POST** ?

Обычно (видимо какие-то изменения в http прошли мимо меня) запрос **HEAD** обрабатывается сервером (для статики) как **GET**, но результат не передается, а динамический ресурс (CGI, php и т.п.) часто вообще не исполняется.

--

Более того, мне показалось (?) что в вопросе на stackoverflow речь шла про download (а не Upload), т.е. загрузке файла с сервера на клиент, т.е. по сути о **GET** 

==*места мало, но думаю дальше все понятно ?*==

Comment: Да, сглупил. Впредь буду внимательным!)